# How to refer to color name defined by a theme package in .emacs?

Tags: emacs, colors, themes

How do I refer to a color name that is defined by a color theme in another part of emacs?

In `base16-solarized-dark-theme.el`file the following colors are defined:

```
(deftheme base16-solarized-dark)

(let ((base00 "#002b36")
      (base01 "#073642")
      (base02 "#586e75")
      (base03 "#657b83")
      (base04 "#839496")
      (base05 "#93a1a1")
      (base06 "#eee8d5")
      (base07 "#fdf6e3")
      (base08 "#dc322f")
      (base09 "#cb4b16")
      (base0A "#b58900")
      (base0B "#859900")
      (base0C "#2aa198")
      (base0D "#268bd2")
      (base0E "#6c71c4")
      (base0F "#d33682"))
```

Now, I'm trying to define the face colors for the `auto-complete` package in my .emacs like this:

```
     (set-face-foreground 'ac-candidate-face "base02")
     (set-face-background 'ac-candidate-face "base0A")
```

But it doesn't work. Emacs doesn't give any error, but the colors don't get defined like that.

Comment: @phils provided the explanation of the problem.  Presumably those variables do not change value in the solarized-theme code. I so then they are really just named constants. So just refer to those colors by their (constant) values: `"#002b36"` etc. Or if you want to use nicer names then bind your own local variables to these strings, using `let` the same way.

Comment: @Drew the idea was to change those colours automatically if I changed the theme. This way it would be hard coded to only work nicely with Solarized and nothing else, this is not what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure without seeing the rest of the code, but in this particular case, the chances are that you *can't* refer to them by name.

`let` bindings are only in scope while the body of the `let` form is being evaluated.

Whatever is going on in the body of that form presumably makes use of those named values, but the symbols don't continue to hold those values afterwards.

FYI if they did you would refer to them as, e.g., `base0A`, rather than `"base0A"` -- the former being a symbol which evaluates to the value assigned to it, whereas the latter is a string value (which *could* be interned to get at the variable of that name, but typically wouldn't be if there wasn't a good reason for it).